# Using the basic identities of sets, establish the identity [C ∩ (A ∪ B)] ∪ [(A ∪ B) ∩ C ′] = A ∪ B.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

Prove that $[C \cap (A \cup B)] \cup [(A \cup B) \cap C^{\prime}] = A ∪ B$.

I arrived at a part of the proof where "$C^{\prime} \cap  A$". Would the answer to that be "$A$" or "$\emptyset$"?
I'm not sure about the answer to that.

Comment: Welcome. Please describe your problem in the title more specifically. Also, “where $C’\cap A$” is an unclear / unfinished sentence - it’s hard to know what you need help with

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "the basic identities of sets", but I guess that you are not supposed to solve it using a case-by-case analysis.
Perhaps you can try to use the identity $(X\cap Z) \cup (Y\cap Z) = (X\cup Y)\cap Z$.